# kafka 0.9.0.1 fails with FATAL exception on startup

Tags: apache-kafka

I tested failover cases for kafka 0.9.0.1 and caught the next exception on startup(server is not started):

```
[2016-03-07 16:30:53,495] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
kafka.common.InvalidOffsetException: Attempt to append an offset (211046544) to position 40048 no larger than the last offset appended (211046546) to xyz/00000000000210467262.index.
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$append$1.apply$mcV$sp(OffsetIndex.scala:207)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$append$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:197)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex$$anonfun$append$1.apply(OffsetIndex.scala:197)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:262)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.append(OffsetIndex.scala:197)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.recover(LogSegment.scala:188)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegments$4.apply(Log.scala:188)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegments$4.apply(Log.scala:160)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:778)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:777)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:160)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:90)
        at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:150)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:60)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Probably it's the problem described here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3047.

Could anyone suggest how to start server?